# Where to find the output of "system out" in Intellij IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea

It seems that system.out will never be displayed in Intellij IDE, is that right? There's no output in Console and Logcat.

Thanks

Comment: If you mean Java EE applications, take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656596/system-out-println-where-does-it-write-to-in-intellij-idea/45494495#45494495

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is seen in the `Run` tab along with the command line to run the program:

[image]

Comment: what if I run a gradle build?