# System.out.println where does it write to in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console, output

I can't find the terminal where the message is supposed to show. How is it called?
I'm guessing it should be in View->Tool Windows but nothing from there seems to work. It's a Maven project and all I can see is GlassFish log.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`System.out` and `System.err` output is written to either the `Run` or the `Debug` tool window depending on whether you launch the run/debug configuration as Run or Debug. See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-and-debugging.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-tool-window.html for more information (Same information is in the Help guide of the IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version).

Comment: Look for the debug tool tab on the bottom of the screen, once opened it has a console tab you can click into.

Answer (score 7):

In Java EE applications with Tomcat container, if you want to see the result of prints like `System.out.println()`, first go to Run > Edit Configurations and select your tomcat server in the left menu, then open Logs tab and check 'Show console when a message is printed to standard output stream'

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working on Wildfly 16.  I've checked the box for showing console when message is printed, yet nothing shows up from System.out.println.   Switching to java.util.logging works though.  Odd.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the below image to figure out.

For running mode:

**View -> Tool Windows -> Run**

For debugging mode:

**View -> Tool Windows -> Debug**

You must be on one of the above two states in order to accomplish this action.

[image: How to show the terminal window on IntelliJ]

Answer (score 0):

This can be happening because the IDE is delegating the task to another build tool like Maven.

If this is the case then you would not see any output in the run window of IntelliJ.

This flag is present at - **setting -> build,execution,deployment -> build tool -> maven (in my case) -> runner -> delegate actions to maven**