# Can not find output for println in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5

Tags: intellij-idea

I am beginner with java and with IntellJ. I did my 'Hello-world' but result does not appear anywhere. I did search for help and I found many this kind of answers like this, which does not help me: [Where to find the output of "system out" in Intellij IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555216/where-to-find-the-output-of-system-out-in-intellij-ide?newreg=4caca0b15aa24dabb42a3c69087aecb6)

In my case, output lines are just skipped, only beginning and end lines are existing. Please, anyone can help? I include the snapshot of my screen
[image: Snapshot of my screen]

Comment: I guess you are not able to see console output

Comment: Just go to Window-->view-->Console and check the output is there are not

Comment: Are you sure you are running the correct program? On top of the console segment it says "Main" while your class is named "Hello". Try to hit one of the "play"-buttons on the left side of your editor and choose "Run Hello.main()".

Comment: Are u running iml file?

Comment: Thank you! It worked to run 'Hello' separately! Now I see println output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the main method of a class called "Main" as you can see at the top of the console (little tab that reads "Main").
By default IntelliJ uses the class name that contains the main method as name of the so called run configuration. You can change that in the top right as well (little combobox with the same content as the tab -> Edit Configurations).

To now correctly run your "Hello" program that contains the output use one of the play buttons next to the editor. That should then add a new tab with the text "Hello" on it which should have your desired output in the console.

Comment: Thank you! It helped and now I can see output for my println. I opened top-right combo and changed there value in the field 'Main class' to 'com.company.Hello.'